# HAXM 1.1.0 not loading x86 atom image on fresh Yosemite install (core 2 duo)

Tags: android, android-emulator, haxm

I can run ARM images, but when I try to run an Atom x86 image (android 4.4.2, nexus 5 clone), it goes to a black screen and sits there doing nothing. The emulator output reports "HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode" before going to the black screen emulator window.

- "AVD_for_Nexus_5", Android 4.4.2, Atom x86
- Hardware: 2.8 GHz Core 2 Duo (Macbook Pro 17, mid2009)
- Fresh install of Yosemite, no virtualization software installed besides HAXM
- HAXM 1.1.0 for "10.9 and above" installed, downloaded from Intel's webiste yesterday
- GPU: have tried both enabled/disabled with no effect: black screen either way

Never had an older version of HAXM installed, so don't think its the "old haxm verison doesn't work on mavericks/yosemite" problem.

Comment: You can try the HAXM in the Android SDK extras. Also if you are using Android Studio you can see logs from Run tab.

Comment: I tried the haxm from android sdk extras too... same result.

Comment: I'm also seeing this on a Core 2 Duo. There's something in the HAXM release notes about not working for 64-bit images on older processors like the Core 2 Duo, but I think we're both trying to run a 32-bit image and it's still failing. This is making me sad, as it's stopping me doing a lot of the Android work I had on my list.

Comment: Anyone with a core 2 duo have HAXM working? Are you using a Mac @MattGibson ?

Comment: Yup, I'm on a 2009 iMac.

Comment: same problem for me, similar details (ARM images ok, ATOM ones end up with black screen; haxm 1.1.1, core2 duo (MBP mid-2009) running mavericks.  Have virtualbox installed, but not running.)

Comment: I am also trying to run x86 android emulator on my 2009 mac (Yosemite) with HAXM 1.1.1 but it don't work. Emulator doesn't boot.